# How to insert Mysql with limit and Continue using foreach PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 100k data. My server is only able to insert 20k data. How do you insert data with a limit then insert again until 100k data is inserted

code :

```
 $url_setting = LIBRARY_PATH.'data/uploads/document/dataSettin.json';  
 $jsondata_setting = file_get_contents($url_setting); 
 $data_setting = json_decode($jsondata_setting, true);

foreach ($data_setting as $key=>$row) 
{
$insert_sql = array(                            
   'PROMO_CODE' => $row['PROMO_CODE'],  
   'PROMO_NAME' => $row['PROMO_NAME'],      
   'DISCOUNT_TYPE' => $row['DISCOUNT_TYPE'],        
   'PROMO_PRIORITY'=> $row['PROMO_PRIORITY'],       
   'PROCESS_TYPE'  => $row['PROCESS_TYPE'],         
   'PROMO_STATUS'  => $row['PROMO_STATUS'],         
   'CREATED'       => $row['CREATED'],          
   'CREATEDBY'     => $row['CREATEDBY'],        
   'UPDATED'       => $row['UPDATED'],          
   'UPDATEDBY'     => $row['UPDATEDBY'],  
                  );
  $db->insert('M_PROMO_SETTING', $insert_sql); 
}
```

I've tried inserting 20k data, success. But more than 20k data an error occurs

Comment: MySQL doesn't have such a small limit on the amount of data you can insert. Databases can store many gigabytes of data. What error are you getting when you try to store more than 20k?

Comment: If I were you, I will generate a CSV with PHP, and let MySQL to import the CSV file via `LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/data.csv' INTO TABLE ...` command.

Comment: You can only hit such kind of limits if you pack several rows into a single `INSERT` statement, and you don't seem to be doing that. My guess is that you're loading and decoding your entire data set into RAM and PHP runs out of memory, and perhaps you haven't configured PHP to [report errors](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) so blaming MySQL is a guess.

Answer (score 0):

We can insert bulk data into a database using for-loop pagination logic. We need to find the `total number of pages` using the `total records` and the `total number of records` we want to insert in one request.

You can refer below function

```
function processInsertData()
{
    $totalRecords = 100000;
    $pageLimit = 100;
    $totalPages = math.ceil($totalRecords/$pageLimit);
    $currentPageNumber = 1;

    for(let i=$currentPageNumber; i <=$totalPages; i++ ){
      // get data using current page number and record $pageLimit
      //if you are fetching from CSV then read from total records fetched from CSV
      //if you are using another table and use page page and page limit in sql LIMIT case
      
      // For example we are reading data from csv
      echo "Current page".$currentPageNumber." Out of ".$totalPages;
      $fetchedRecords = [];
      if(count($fetchedRecords)>0){
        $insertResponse = insertData($fetchedRecords);
        if($insertResponse){
          // increment page size by 1   
          $currentPageNumber++;
        }
      }
      else {
        echo "All data inserted successfully";
      }
    }
}
```